# Why is a signal handler I establish with signal() or sigaction() ignored?

Tags: c++, signals, raspberry-pi3

I've got the following issue: I would like to catch `SIGINT` (and later, also `SIGTERM`) `signals` while my code is running on my Raspberry Pi 3 (with the recent Raspbian) in order to do some clean-up (particularly, closing a connection to a USB device) when I stop my (C++ 11) program. First I tried out `signal ()`, but the signal handler never kicked in. Instead, I got this message on my console after hitting ^C:

```
2017-02-26 17:13:17 sigHandler: Unhandled signal 2, terminating
```

The [signal manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) recommends to use `sigaction()` instead. OK, I took [this tutorial](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/05/20/tap-the-interrupt-signal/) to replace `signal()` with `sigaction()`, but no use, the handler is never called. After reading a bunch of other tutorials (like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/16430/)), I finally ended up with this code snippet:

```
void OnSignalCaught (int signal)
{
  cout << "Exited." << endl;
  exit (signal);
}

int main ()
{
  struct sigaction exit_action;
  struct sigaction old_action;
  int              ret;

  sigemptyset (&exit_action.sa_mask);

  exit_action.sa_handler = OnSignalCaught;
  exit_action.sa_flags   = 0;
  ret                    = sigaction (SIGINT, &exit_action, &old_action);

  if (ret < 0) cout << "Creating signal handler failed! Error code: " << errno << "." << endl;

// remainder of the code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been running exactly your code. I only added the missing headers, and it works, the signal hangler got called.

Comment: In the meantime, I've at least managed to pinpoint the issue: It, in fact, lies in the line of code which, in the complete code (not in the snippet I posted above), is situated right behind the sigaction() call: gpioInitialise() from the pigpio library! It seems to reset all signal handler links, so that the handler is never called upon ^C. I simply put gpioInitialise () before calling sigaction (), and now everything works fine. ^^